# Consistently getting errors with mongodb import and export statements

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to import a file into my mongodb collection, named `sales.json`

I'm running the program from my windowsOS terminal `mongo --version` returns normal `MongoDB shell version v4.4.1`

Connecting to my database seems to work `"mongodb+srv://sandbox.dmuuh.mongodb.net/sandbox" --username helloworld` gets me access `<MongoDB Enterprise atlas-10vof1-shard-0:PRIMARY>`

However, whenever I try running the command

```
mongoimport --uri="mongodb+srv://m001-student:m001-mongodb-basics@sandbox.mongodb.net/sample_supplies" sales.json
```

I get the error

```
SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier : @(shell):1:13
```

I've also tried

```
 mongoimport --help
```

and

```
 mongoexport --collection=sample_supplies --db=admin --out=sample.json
```

which both returns the same error. It seems to me that the error is "--", but I wouldn't get why that would be an issue. Something that may contribute to this error might be that my shell is 4.4 but it seems my server is 4.2, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: You are probably missing the `--file sales.json`. See the [Examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongoimport/index.html#examples). It is the syntax to specify the input JSON file. You need to use the `--file` paramater .

Comment: @prasad_ `mongoimport --uri="mongodb+srv://m001-student-mongodb-basics@sandbox.mongodb.net/sample_supplies" --file=sales.json` still returns same error

Comment: `mongoimport` is s command-line program - are you running it from operating system command-line?

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, I'm running it from terminal on windows OS